# additional public IP and local network

Tags: ip, router, port-forwarding, subnet

Currently we have router A that does all the routing/firewalling/forwarding/dhcp/... services. It also forwards ports 80 and 443 to server on our local network.

We need second web server(not as a backup, but different content) for which we ordered additional public IP. My problem is how to properly integrate that additional public IP to out network and successfully use it for second web server.

I would rather leave current router A as it is(it is quite old, does not supports multiple public IPs, has already a lot of rules,...). And I can't add additional network cabling between router and server, that means I have to use existing cabling and switching to servers. So I was thinking to add a second router B, firstly to set it up just for second public IP and second web server behind it. I connect router B to ISPs switch and configure second public IP to it. Then I connect router B(with disabled DHCP) to existing network switch(which is already connected to existing roter A). My question is how to set routers B local network. I was thinking there are two options:

1. configure it in the same subnet as router A - 192.168.1.0/24 (+avoid already used local IPs)
2. configure it in own new subnet 192.168.2.0/24, and still connect it to existing switch and put second web server to that subnet

First option uses existing subnet, I have two gateways but router Bs is not used anywhere except on second webserver. Is that ok from networking standpoint?

Second option adds new subnet. Does that make any problems to the existing network?

In both cases router B forwards ports to second web server.

Are my plans right or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a proper router. pfSense can be very cheap, or free if you have unused old hardware around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the choices you are considering, either should work fine, but since you have to use the same network cabling/switching, it's probably a better (as in best practice) solution to go with the same LAN network. Having two gateways is perfectly fine from a networking standpoint.

Having two IP networks on the same physical network is also perfectly fine (as long as you don't need separation between them for security reasons), but it is generally not best practice, because of the potential for confusion. (And often there are security concerns because of users on network A being able to simply change their IP and jump on network B, but in your case it doesn't sound like that applies.) Normally, if you have multiple IP networks, you separate them with either a completely separate physical network, or more commonly separate logical networks like VLANs.

I understand your reasoning for keeping the old router as-is, and it is legitimate, however, with a situation like this, you really should consider replacing it. There are many options for that, free and paid, that will do the job very nicely. But if you don't or can't make that decision then what you have suggested above will work fine.

Another option is that you could use just the one IP address and same web server to serve both websites. Virtual hosts allow you to do this with one IP address on different domains, with completely different content of course.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Confusion with second IP network was my concern too. In my case I don't see internal security issue with "jumping" between networks. Best practices are my objectives and your answer provides them. Can you please give examples for free/open source solutions you mentioned and that could solve my problem?

Comment: @ForestJerry Sure: pFSense is probably the most notable and widely used, but there is also IPCop, Untangle NG Firewall, Smoothwall, and m0n0wall. Any of these should meet your needs.